# EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when using getline() in ifstream

Tags: c++, xcode, exc-bad-access, ifstream

I have been running into this `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` issue a lot lately when developing in C++ using Xcode. This time, I can't figure out what is wrong though.

I have this function that should be simple enough, just a way to count how many lines are in a file:

```cpp
int getNumLines(string file)
{
    int lineCount = 0;
    string line;
    ifstream textFile;
    textFile.open(file);
    if( textFile.is_open() && !textFile.ios_base::fail() )
    {
        while(getline(textFile, line))
        {
            lineCount++;
        }
    }
    textFile.close();
    return lineCount;
}
```

Every time I run my code, I get this line of errors leading back to the `fstream` class file, and the error code:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x7000000070)

Here is where this error leads:

[image]

I'm not sure what's causing this issue. Zombie objects don't seem to help me find the source of the problem, or perhaps I am just not understanding how to enable them properly.

Comment: You're going to need a [mre] because for all we know you have rampaging gremlins on line 32767 and they ate up all of your automatic memory causing a Stack overflow. The real beauty of the MRE is it's a powerful debugging tool. As you get closer and closer to the ideal MRE, the more likely the reduced noise surrounding the bug exposes both the problem and its solution. If you include manufacturing a MRE early in the start the question writing process odds are good you won't have to ask the question.

Comment: `textFile.ios_base::fail()` looks unusual, though. I'd take a closer look at it.

Comment: @user4581301 I tried what you said with making a MRE for everything that should affect this function and it had no errors, so I guess the gremlins are rampaging somewhere. I'm not really sure how to figure out what might be taking up my memory. How should I look for that?

Comment: There is no problem in this code (though the `fail()` check is redundant and should be removed).  You likely have *undefined behavior* elsewhere in your code, like maybe a buffer overflow or something that is corrupting memory, and this function is the unwitting victim.

Comment: Are you building your code with all warnings enabled?  If so, does it build cleanly?  If possible, try building your program with gcc or clang and turn on the address sanitizer.

Comment: MRE doesn't always work, but if the MRE doesn't end with you seeing the mistake, add the MRE to the question. Someone will see the slip-up.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help. I found the issue to be how I was handling arrays in the objects I created. I moved everything over to std::array instead of int* and my memory errors went away.